# Use of unresolved identifier 'FBAppCall' in swift

Tags: xcode, swift

Code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        return FBAppCall.handleOpenURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, fallbackHandler: nil);
    }
```

BridgeHeader.h

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
```

I have done facebook integration in my project 
when i try to compile getting error as

> Use of unresolved identifier 'FBAppCall'.

what am i missing? Any help will appreciated.

Comment: try with lastes Fb SDK. so you will not require to Bridge Header in the App.